# Dynamic query in SSIS expression builder throwing an error expression cannot be evaluated

Tags: ssis, dynamic-sql, expressionbuilder

I am working on an example to write dynamic sql to pivot the data in ssis expression builder.It fails to evaluate the expression. Below is the dynamic query:

```
 DECLARE @Cols as NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
SELECT @Cols = COALESCE(@Cols + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM
   (
     SELECT DISTINCT Category
     FROM Product
   ) As t1

SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ProductID,
    Category,
    Quantity
    FROM   Product
) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(Quantity)
   FOR Category IN (" + @Cols + ")
) AS PivotResult'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your double quotes around  + @Cols  needs to be single quotes, see below.

```
DECLARE @Cols as NVARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
SELECT @Cols = COALESCE(@Cols + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM
   (
     SELECT DISTINCT Category
     FROM Product
   ) As t1

SET @SQL = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT ProductID,
    Category,
    Quantity
    FROM   Product
) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(Quantity)
   FOR Category IN (' + @Cols + ')
) AS PivotResult'
```

Comment: I tried that it's still failing to evaluate.

Comment: I may have missed you are doing this in expression builder, why not do it directly in an Execute SQL task.  You can run this directly in SQL task or even create SP out of it and just call the SP